# Python: Solving a second order differential equation with complex initial conditions

Tags: python, numpy, math, complex-numbers, differential-equations

I want to solve a second order differential equation with variable coefficients by using something like odeint. The problem with this one is that it doesn't work if the initial conditions are complex (which is the case now).

Do you know a way to solve the aforementioned equation with something similar to odeint?

Comment: "Complex initial conditions" - can you describe them?  Complex in what sense?   How do they vary?  What is the independent variable?   Initial means "at time zero", so I have trouble imagining where else the complexity can come from.

Answer (score 2):

[`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) does not accept complex variables.  You could use: the newer solver, [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html); the older [`ode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) class with the "zvode" integrator; or [`odeintw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw), a wrapper of `odeint` that I wrote that handles complex-valued and matrix-valued differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

You could always work with the real components (`odeint` convention)

```
def odesys(u,t):
    z = u[0]+1j*u[1]
    dz = u[2]+1j*u[3]
    d2z = f(t,z,dz)
    return [ dz.real, dz.imag, d2z.real, d2z.imag ]
```

where `f` stands for the explicit form of the second order ODE.

If I remember correctly, one of the methods ("vzode"?) that you can use in `scipy.integrate.ode` works directly with complex state variables.